# Better photo viewer for GMail photo attachments

Tags: gmail, photos

Surprised that GMail still doesn't have a better built in photo viewer when an email includes photo attachments - especially large ones.

Currently, the only option is a small-ish preview below the message body (which doesn't always render, especially with larger photo files) or clicking VIEW which opens the photo in a new tab/window.  This is especially problematic when the image files are large (2+ MB)

Yahoo has had quite an elegant built in photo attachment viewer [for some time](http://www.ymailblog.com/blog/2008/05/yahoo-mail-photo-viewer/)

Question is - is there a GMail add-on/widget (or even browser extension...) that improves this experience?

Answer (score 1):

Well, GMail gives an option to add your email photos to Google Docs and to Picasa directly.
Picasa has a nice viewer: http://picasaweb.google.com

Comment: I'm a huge picasaweb fan, but ideally I'm looking for something similar to Yahoo's viewer that lets you easily and quickly view large, multiple photos attached to an email

Comment: @3rdparty Gmail has inbuilt image viewer which comes up when you open the mail with photos attached. This shows images in not really the same size, but you can take a quick view at them.
Well, the company which prepared your favorite Yahoo photos viewer, first made an addon which enabled the same features in Gmail which all you are accessing in Yahoo. And on top of that they had a website where you can go and all your email photos attachment can be browsed with some great search and view features. Anyways, the addon is not there in Gmail now. BTW, this was a Firefox addon they had introduced.

Comment: Do you recall the name of the company or Firefox extension?

Comment: @3rdparty: Sadly that site has gone to Yahoo! and now does not serve for GMail. Its the same company which has built the Yahoo! Mail Photo storage and viewer.
Well, on the other side GMail Labs has an addon which can provide you quick photo view and very well even if there is only Picasa Web link in the email.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of [backupthat](http://www.backupthat.com) to view all of my attachments.  They have a great product that organizes, sorts, and finds all of the attachments I need quickly so I don't have to look through all the email threads to find what I need.